# Passing a function a string

Tags: c++, function, vector

I currently have a program that takes data in from a dat file and forms a 2-dimensional vector. Right now, I have 10 dat files and 10 different functions that each create a vector. I was wondering how I can shorten the code and create one function that creates the 2-d vectors by passing a string with the name of the dat file. Below I have listed a couple of the functions.

```
vector<vector<double> > Cosmic_ray_events()  
{
const double columns = 8.;
ifstream cosmic_ray_data("events_comp-h4a_10.00-10000.00PeV_zen37.00.dat", ios::in);
vector< vector<double> > cosmic_ray;

while(cosmic_ray_data.good())     
{
    vector <double> row_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        double data;
        cosmic_ray_data >> data;
        row_vector.push_back(data);
    }
    cosmic_ray.push_back(row_vector);
    //cout << cosmic_ray[i][data];
}
cosmic_ray_data.close();

for(double k = 0; k < cosmic_ray.size(); k++)
{
    for (double z = 0; z < cosmic_ray[k].size(); z++)
    {
        cout << cosmic_ray[k][z] << "  " << endl;       
    }
}

return(cosmic_ray);
}

vector<vector<double> > IC40_events()  
{
const double columns = 8.;
     ifstream IC40_events_data("IC40_exp.dat", ios::in);
     vector< vector<double> > IC40;

    while(IC40_events_data.good())
   {
      vector <double> row_vector1;
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        double IC40_data;
        IC40_events_data >> IC40_data;
        row_vector1.push_back(IC40_data);
    }
    IC40.push_back(row_vector1);
}
IC40_events_data.close();

return(IC40);
```

}
 code here

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you do this

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > readDAT(std::string const &path)
{
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > data;

   const int columns = 8;  // pass as a parameter?
   ifstream instream(path, ios::in);

   while( data_good(instream) ) // you don't provide cosmic_data_good
   {
      std::vector<double> line;
      for(int i= 0; i < columns; i++)
      {
         double datum;
         instream >> datum;
         line.push_back(datum);
      }
      data.push_back(line);
   }

   return data;
}
```

The files consist of columns of 8 real numbers. So they can all be read with the same routine. If the number of columns varies, you can pass it in and make columns a variable instead of a constant, that's just a minor change. You also need some way of detecting end of data, which I imagine the data_good() functions will be doing.

Another trick is to take an opened istream, and open the file in a  wrapper function. Then you can load .DAT data from any source, not just a disk file.

Call it like this

```
 vector<vector<double> > cosmic_ray = readDAT("events_comp-h4a_10.00-10000.00PeV_zen37.00.dat");
 vector<vector<double> > IC40_events = readDAT("IC40_exp.dat");
```

And so on, for all your data sets.

Comment: How can I check that this will read and create all the necessary 2-d vectors?

Comment: That's your is_good() function. It returns false when data is exhausted, assuming that the code you posted is correct. (It's a lot easier to use the C interface to streams, but that's another topic).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still failing to understand how this code will call the 10 different dat files and produce all the necessary vectors.